# DocumentPicker throwing Cannot read property 'pick' of null error

Tags: react-native, expo

Hello i'm trying to upload pdf files using react native i'm using DocumentPicker however i keep getting the error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pick' of null]` please note that i'm using expo

This is how impoting DocumentPicker :

```
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker'
```

This is my openFilePicker:

```
  const openFilePicker = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('DocumentPicker', DocumentPicker)
      const res = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.pdf],
      });
      console.log(
           res.uri,
           res.type, // mime type
           res.name,
           res.size,
  );
    } catch (err) {
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        // User cancelled the picker, exit any dialogs or menus and move on
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  };
```

This is my button:

```
      <Button
        title="Select PDF"
        color={"green"}
        onPress={openFilePicker}
      />
```

Comment: yes i actually managed to make it work using await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync isntead of await DocumentPicker.pickSingle

Comment: Thanks even I made it work but a different way

Comment: Could you show us how you made it work ?

Comment: @JheyssonUrbano you can use:
const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type: "image/*",
        multiple: true, // Allow multiple image selection
        copyToCacheDirectory: false,
      }); ..... Rest of your code